# Mockery to define multiple possible values to an expectation

Tags: php, mockery

I am trying to declare an expectation that has two possible values as a parameter, based on the value I want the return value to be different.

Here is what I tried

```
$mock = m::mock('FooBar\ClassA');
$mock->shouldReceive('has')->with('foo')->andReturn(false);
$mock->shouldReceive('has')->with('bar')->andReturn(true);
```

I get this error

> Mockery\Exception\NoMatchingExpectationException: No matching handler
>   found for Mockery_2__FooBar_ClassA::has("bar")

I read through http://docs.mockery.io/en/latest/reference/expectations.html

but I am unable to find the answer. I am trying to resort to solving the problem with `andReturnUsing` which is straight-forward. Is there a way to solve the problem without using `andReturnUsing`?

```
$mock->shouldReceive('has')->andReturnUsing(function ($value) {
    switch ($value) {
    case 'foo': return false;
    case 'bar': return true;
    }
});
```

I also read [Mockery specifying expected arguments for multiple calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26510007/mockery-specifying-expected-arguments-for-multiple-calls)

But that's the same thing I have tried, it forces validation on parameter type.

Answer (score 1):

ok i found the answer

```
$mock->shouldReceive('has')->withArgs(['foo'])->andReturnValues([false]);
$mock->shouldReceive('has')->withArgs(['bar'])->andReturnValues([true]);
```

since `withArgs` is just a wrapper around `with` i think it is also possible to use `with`, but i think the param has to be inside an array